# De-duplicating data frame using aggregation function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below. I would like to remove the duplicate occurrences of the key tuple (`Parameter`, `Value`) and pick the one with the minimum `mse`.

```
> df
              mse     Parameter Value
    1    25.86760 Training_size   100
    2     8.42944 Training_size   200
    3    58.80860 Training_size   300
    4    34.37760 Training_size   400
    5    99.61530 Training_size   500
    6    19.77290 Training_size   600
    7    24.76670 Training_size   700
    8   587.96900 Training_size   800
    9   538.02500 Training_size   900
    10   60.39630 Training_size  1000
    11  137.07600 Training_size  2000
    12   62.05740 Training_size  3000
    13    8.44762 Training_size   200
    14    8.44610 Training_size   200
    15    8.44871 Training_size   200
    16    8.42939 Training_size   200
    17   11.78550 Training_size   200
    18   11.78520 Training_size   200
    19 1726.44000 Training_size   200
    20 1726.44000 Training_size   200
    21 1726.43000 Training_size   200
    22    8.42939 Training_size   200
    23    8.42942 Training_size   200
    24    8.42939 Training_size   200
    25    8.42938 Training_size   200
```

I would like to instead get:

```
              mse     Parameter Value
    1    25.86760 Training_size   100
    3    58.80860 Training_size   300
    4    34.37760 Training_size   400
    5    99.61530 Training_size   500
    6    19.77290 Training_size   600
    7    24.76670 Training_size   700
    8   587.96900 Training_size   800
    9   538.02500 Training_size   900
    10   60.39630 Training_size  1000
    11  137.07600 Training_size  2000
    12   62.05740 Training_size  3000
    25    8.42938 Training_size   200
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate` function in base

```
> aggregate(.~Value+Parameter, data=df, FUN=min)
   Value     Parameter       mse
1    100 Training_size  25.86760
2    200 Training_size   8.42938
3    300 Training_size  58.80860
4    400 Training_size  34.37760
5    500 Training_size  99.61530
6    600 Training_size  19.77290
7    700 Training_size  24.76670
8    800 Training_size 587.96900
9    900 Training_size 538.02500
10  1000 Training_size  60.39630
11  2000 Training_size 137.07600
12  3000 Training_size  62.05740
```

Comment: both solve the OP but your solution is more elegant and simpler. I also don't need non standard packages and don't need to rename the `mse` back after running it like in the other solution. Thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I wouldn't be that dismissive with packages, R is all about them. I'd say plyr is a de facto standard package, together with reshape2 and maybe ggplot2. I get what you mean answer-wise, of course :)

Comment: @GiovanniAzua What if you need the min and max by Value+Parameter?

Comment: but I don't, I only need the minimum mse, not interested in the maximum but thank you for bringing it up.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use for the big data, then you can consider using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(mydata)
setkey(DT,Parameter,Value)  # optional, for further speed
DT[,min(mse),by="Parameter,Value"]
        Parameter Value        V1
 1: Training_size   100  25.86760
 2: Training_size   200   8.42938
 3: Training_size   300  58.80860
 4: Training_size   400  34.37760
 5: Training_size   500  99.61530
 6: Training_size   600  19.77290
 7: Training_size   700  24.76670
 8: Training_size   800 587.96900
 9: Training_size   900 538.02500
10: Training_size  1000  60.39630
11: Training_size  2000 137.07600
12: Training_size  3000  62.05740
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the process of 'remove duplicate occurences of the key tuple (`Parameter`, `value`) is contained within the process of "pick the one with the minimum `mse`". Really (if I've understood correctly) you just want to build a data frame containing the minimum value of `mse` for each unique combination of `Parameter` and `value`. (Note that tuple is not a defined data type in R.

The `plyr` package is perfect for this.

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, c("Parameter", "value"), summarise, min(mse))
```